# FileDownload Primefaces error Stream Closed

Tags: jsf, primefaces

I have a table with users and a i have to select one to get the list of files so i can download. Everything works fine but if i already download the file and i try to click again to download i get the **java.io.IOException: Stream Closed** , but if i download the file and select again the user to get the list of files i can download the file.

The problem is i can't download more than once without have to select the user and get the list of files.

This is how i get the files when i select the user to get the list of files.

```
public void obtenerRequisitos() {

    try {
        archivos = new ArrayList<>();
        lstArchivos = new ArrayList<>();
        if (SelectedInscripcion != null) {
        lstArchivos = d.getArchivosInscripciones(String.valueOf(SelectedInscripcion.getId()));

        for (Archivos a : lstArchivos) {
            InputStream input = new FileInputStream(a.getRuta());
            String extension = a.getRuta().substring(a.getRuta().lastIndexOf('.'));
            file = new DefaultStreamedContent(input, a.getRequisitosPromo().getRequisitos().getTipoArchivo(), a.getRequisitosPromo().getRequisitos().getFormato() + extension);
            archivos.add(new ClsArchivos(a.getRequisitosPromo().getRequisitos().getDescripcion(), file));
        }
    }
    } catch (Exception ex) {
        Logger.getLogger(AsignarEntrevistaBean.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);

    }

}
```

this is a class that i use to store the list of files

```
    public class ClsArchivos implements Serializable{

    private String descripcion;
    private StreamedContent file;

    public String getDescripcion() {
        return descripcion;
    }

    public void setDescripcion(String descripcion) {
        this.descripcion = descripcion;
    }

    public StreamedContent getFile() {
        return file;
    }

    public void setFile(StreamedContent file) {
        this.file = file;
    }

    public ClsArchivos() {
    }

    public ClsArchivos(String descripcion, StreamedContent file) {
        this.descripcion = descripcion;
        this.file = file;        
    }  
}
```

and this is part of the xhtml where the filedownload is

```
<p:dataTable style="margin-bottom: 25px;" id="requisitos" value="#{asignarEntrevistaBean.archivos}" var="a">
                <f:facet name="header">
                    Listas de Requisitos por Solicitud
                </f:facet>
                <p:column headerText="Descripcion">
                    <h:outputText value="#{a.descripcion}" />
                </p:column>
                <p:column headerText="Archivos">
                    <p:commandButton   value="Download" ajax="false"  icon="ui-icon-arrowthick-1-s">
                        <p:fileDownload value="#{a.file}" />
                    </p:commandButton>
                </p:column>                    
            </p:dataTable>
```